# Virtual host on Mamp Pro not working

Tags: virtual, virtualhost, host, mamp-pro

Am new to Mamp Pro though I've been using plain Mamp for a while. Using MacBookPro running Yosemite.

Mamp's default localhost server is working fine and in a browser I can open subfolders living in htdocs with no problem and they behave like sites.

But I set up a virtual host in the Mamp Pro interface, e.g., clientname. The folder 'clientname' lives in the Mamp htdocs folder. Have restarted Mamp. When I try to view the site (clicking on the arrow in the Mamp Pro interface) in a browser (Firefox) it wants to download a file rather than opening the home page. Safari simply shows a blank page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, was a problem of file suffix. With the site set up in this way, on a virtual Mamp Pro server, browsers wouldn't open index.html, it had to be index.php

I don't understand why this should be especially as that page has only static content and doesn't need to connect with the database and doesn't contain a php include file or any php code at all.

If anyone knows why the page has to be .php I'd be interested to understand the issue.